# Julia Gtk - присваивание значения в callback функции

Tags: gtk, julia

Я пытаюсь освоить Julia Language и пишу игру "пять в ряд" с использованием Julia Gtk. Вот мои текущие наброски для интерфейса:

```
using Gtk

cur_step = "x"

function click_once_callback(widget)
    set_gtk_property!(widget, :sensitive, false)
    set_gtk_property!(widget, :label, cur_step)
    if cur_step == "x"
        cur_step = "o"
    else
        cur_step = "x"
    end
end

letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o']

win = GtkWindow("GoMoku")
g = GtkGrid()

buttons = []

for i=1:15
    b = []
    for j=1:15
        letter = letters[i]
        push!(b,GtkButton("$letter:$j"))
    end
    push!(buttons,b)
end

for i=1:15
    for j=1:15
        g[i,16-j] = buttons[i][j]
        id = signal_connect(click_once_callback, buttons[i][j], "clicked")
    end
end


set_gtk_property!(g, :column_homogeneous, true)
set_gtk_property!(g, :column_spacing, 15)  # introduce a 15-pixel gap between columns
set_gtk_property!(g, :row_spacing, 15)  # introduce a 15-pixel gap between rows
push!(win, g)
showall(win)
```

Проблема:
Переменная cur_step не меняется из callback функции, и вообще при попытке её изменить label кнопок не устанавливается в значение cur_step. Если убрать всю работу с cur_step в функции, кроме установки его значения в label текущей кнопки, то все работает как положено - кнопка получает надпись "x" после нажатия, и прекращает быть активной.

Я пытался объявить переменную cur_step через global, это не решило проблему.
Подскажите пожалуйста, почему работа с переменной вне функции вызывает такие эффекты?

Comment: Вопрос должен быть закрыт, так как на [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь [Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Спасибо, перевел на русский язык

Answer (score 0):

Ответ был найден при помощи англоязычного stackoverflow.
Чтобы переменная была корректно доступна для редактирования внутри функции, необходимо её внутри же функции объявить как global. Таким образом,достаточно было написать global cur_step внутри функции click_once_callback перед всеми обращениями.